# AngularJS Click on TouchStart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

Angular Touch `ngTouch` causes the click to occur on touch release.

Is there a way to make the click happen on touch start?

The `fast-click` directive below seems to do what I want on touchscreens, but it doesn't work with mouse clicks.

```
myApp.directive('fastClick', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr['fastClick']);
      var initX, initY, endX, endY;
      var elem = element;

      elem.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          initX = endX = event.touches[0].clientX;
          initY = endY = event.touches[0].clientY;
          scope.$apply(function () { fn(scope, { $event: event }); });
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `click` to the `touchstart` event - `event.preventDefault()` will cancel the event from happening twice:

```
elem.bind('touchstart click', function (event) {
```

A quick fastclick code that I use in one app is:

```
app.directive("ngMobileClick", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind("touchstart click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            scope.$apply(attrs["ngMobileClick"]);
        });
    }
}])
```

And use like: `ng-mobile-click="myScopeFunction()"`

Comment: @benshope -- I posted some fastclick/touchstart code I use in an app I support, should get the job done.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scope.$apply(attrs["ng-mobile-click"]);` or am I wrong?

Comment: @jstudios -- Those dashes get converted to a camel cased name.

Comment: @tymeJV So it does the opposite of what `app.directive("ngMobileClick"..` does? Where it adds the dashes at each capital letter?

Comment: @jstudios -- Yes, the declared directive is converted

Comment: It's a trap! Just hacking in stopPropagation() might have unplanned consequences, like if you're trying to catch all taps at the <body> level as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of tymeJV is correct but when I've tried to overwrite ngClick directive the behaviour conflicted with ngTouch module - some clicks started firing twice. The reason is simple, ngTouch cares about the stuff but unfortunately has a bug.

In touchstart event handler instead of:

```
  var touches = event.touches && event.touches.length ? event.touches : [event];
```

it should have something like this:

```
var touches = null;
  if (event.touches && event.touches.length) {
      //AC: this is original library case
      touches = event.touches;
  } else if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches && event.originalEvent.touches.length) {
      //AC: this is fix actually working
      touches =  event.originalEvent.touches;
  }else{
    touches = [event];
  }
```

i.e. event's touches field is undefined for some reason, but event.originalEvent.touches is fine.

The same should be done in touchend:

```
var touches = null;
  if (event.changedTouches && event.changedTouches.length) {
      //AC: this is original library case
      touches = event.changedTouches;
  } else if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.changedTouches && event.originalEvent.changedTouches.length) {
      //AC: this is fix actually working
      touches = event.originalEvent.changedTouches;
  } else {
      touches = [event];
  }
```

Version of ngTouch is 1.2.27.